# automake native:oe_runmake failed in yocto krogoth

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi3, yocto

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and want to build customized Linux kernel for Raspberry Pi 3 using yocto. I used the bitbake rpi-basic-image command which resulted in these errors:

[image]

Also I haven't got the deploy folder in tmp directory yet

Could you help me on solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include code and errors in the form of text, not screenshots. Also review your post before posting and fix formatting (like the image include here) - weirdly formatted posts are difficult to read for others.

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.